# Trying to create a derived column for bool value based on if a tenant still lives there

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Lease_Agreement`
(
    `ContractID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `StartDate` DATE NOT NULL,
    `Duration` INT NOT NULL,
    `Rent` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    `Live?` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`ContractID`)
);
```

I want a derived bool column (`Live?`) if the Duration in months has not elapsed from the start date until the current date (`DATE.NOW`).

The Duration has to be in months hence the int datatype, anyway i can single out the month in StartDate format (YYYY/MM/DD) then add duration to that and compare it against Date.Now?

```
Live? TINYINT(1) [GENERATED ALWAYS] AS (startDate + Duration < DATE.NOW )
```

Something like this I was attempting. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a function like `now()` in a generated column, because this function is non-deterministic (the value it returns changes every second). This is [well explained in the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html):

> Literals, deterministic built-in functions, and operators are permitted. A function is deterministic if, given the same data in tables, multiple invocations produce the same result, independently of the connected user. Examples of functions that are nondeterministic and fail this definition: `CONNECTION_ID()`, `CURRENT_USER()`, `NOW()`.

As a workaround, you can create a view. Assuming thatt `Duration` is expressed in months (which is not very clear in your question):

```
create view lease_agreement_view (
    ContractID,
    StartDate,
    Duration,
    Rent,
    Is_Live
) as
select
    ContractID,
    StartDate,
    Duration,
    Rent,
    StartDate + interval Duration month < now()
from Lease_Agreement
```

**[Demo on DB FIddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e68ec4311f208012bedb1cbc034a9519)**:

```
insert into Lease_Agreement values 
    (1, '2019-01-01', 10, 1),    -- expired
    (2, '2019-01-01', 12, 1);    -- live

select * from lease_agreement_view
```

```
ContractID | StartDate  | Duration | Rent | Is_Live
---------: | :--------- | -------: | ---: | ------:
         1 | 2019-01-01 |       10 |    1 |       1
         2 | 2019-01-01 |       12 |    1 |       0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to use volatile functions in the definition.  The best you can do is a view:

```
create view v_lease_agreement as
    select la.*, (StartDate + Duration < CURDATE()) as is_live
    from lease_agreement;
```

This is explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html):

> Generated column expressions must adhere to the following rules. An error occurs if an expression contains disallowed constructs.
>
> - Literals, deterministic built-in functions, and operators are permitted. A function is deterministic if, given the same data in tables, multiple invocations produce the same result, independently of the connected user. Examples of functions that are nondeterministic and fail this definition: CONNECTION_ID(), CURRENT_USER(), NOW().

Answer (score 0):

You can Update LIVE?  with an Query and then check for all that are still live

```
UPDATE Lease_Agreement 
  SET `Live?` = IF(DATE_ADD(StartDate, INTERVAL Duration DAY) < NOW(),1,0);; );
```

This sets all Rows to 0  that are passed their Finished time.

Because When You insert a new Row it is always Live i think

see here an example
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9311fe99fdab2b31c0e7c8e367b27b7e